# Counting whole DB while searching for specific SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in db for customers and their glasses

**customer_inventory_tbl**:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_inventory_tbl

+-------+-------+-------+
|id(pk) | name  | spex  |
+-------+-------+-------+
|1      |John   |Oval   |
|2      |Steve  |Angular|
|3      |John   |Aviator|
|4      |Kevin  |Supra  |
|5      |Jamie  |Oval   |
|6      |Ben    |Supra  |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

(this is a way more simplified version, haha)

If I view John's record it shows

```
SELECT * FROM customer_inventory_tbl WHERE name=John

+-------+-------+-------+
|id(pk) | name  | spex  |
+-------+-------+-------+
|1      |John   |Oval   |
|3      |John   |Aviator|
+-------+-------+-------+
```

But what I require is when viewing John's record, it to show me

```
+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|id(pk) | name  | spex  |count|
+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|1      |John   |Oval   |2    |
|3      |John   |Aviator|1    |
+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```

That "count" column is the number of records in the database that has "Oval" for instance.

Now that is easy enough, if I wanted to count every record in the db, but how do I get the count of all records whilst looking for a specific name.

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select c.*,
    (
        select count(1)
        from customer_inventory_tbl
        where spex = c.spex
        ) "count"
from customer_inventory_tbl c;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution according to above mentioned description please try executing following sql query

```
SELECT *,(select count(id) from customer_inventory_tbl group by spex)
 as count FROM customer_inventory_tbl WHERE name='John'
```

In above mentioned sql query counter value is being retrieved through subquery with records grouped according to values of spex column using **GROUP BY** clause.